# Converting list of lists to a data frame in R

Tags: r, data.table

I am working with nested lists in R and am running into a problem with rbindlist.  I have lists that look like this

```
L <- list(list(list(c(0,0)),list(c(0,0)),list(c(33,37))), list(list(c(0,0)),list(c(0,0)),list(c(29,33))))
```

Resulting in:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
[1] 0 0


[[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[2]][[1]]
[1] 0 0


[[1]][[3]]
[[1]][[3]][[1]]
[1] 33 37



[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]]
[1] 0 0


[[2]][[2]]
[[2]][[2]][[1]]
[1] 0 0


[[2]][[3]]
[[2]][[3]][[1]]
[1] 29 33
```

What I am trying to do is collapse each sub-list into a data frame that would look something like this (this result is what I want from the first set of lists above):

```
config alpha start end
1        1     0    0
1        2     0    0
1        3     33   37
2        1     0    0
2        2     0    0
2        3     29   33
```

But some lists have a **different** number of sub-lists relative to the other lists in the sub-list.  For example, a list like this (with 2 sub-lists in the middle instead of 3 1-sublist sub-lists).

```
L <- list(list(c(0,0)), list(c(1,4),c(5,9)), list(c(0,0)) )
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 0 0


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 1 4

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 5 9


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 0 0
```

when I try rbindlist I get this error:

```
> rbindlist(lapply(master_init, as.list))
Error in rbindlist(lapply(master_init, as.list)) : 
  Column 2 of item 50 is length 2, inconsistent with first column of that item which is length 1. rbind/rbindlist doesn't recycle as it already expects each item to be a uniform list, data.frame or data.table
```

I know what the error means but not how to fix it.  Thoughts?

Comment: I don't know how to adapt it to any plyr/data.table fanciness, but `lapply(L, function(x) do.call(rbind,x) )` works.

Comment: I'm not really clear on the desired output corresponding to the reproducible input...?

Comment: I'm curious why you have a list like that in the first place... there's most likely no reason you should have to deal with something like that. Can we perhaps help with whatever created such a complex list? Perhaps there's another question in that?

Comment: @TommyO'Dell, The reason has to do with information loss if the sub-lists are collapsed into one list.  This is common when dealing with partitions of sets where one needs to keep track of the partition level.  It could also be done using an index in another list but would require more work.

In other words, since I've been using lapply extensively throughout the program, I've worked with rather than against the output structure for that function.

Comment: @TommyO'Dell, I would also say that in general lapply seems to work so quickly that it is usually to one's advantage to deal with whatever back-end data conversion is necessary in the name of performance.  This program is executing at 1/50th the speed of my old version which did not use lapply as extensively.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by `melt/dcast`.  We set the names of the `list` elements, `melt` to convert the `list` to `data.frame`.  We create a sequence column ('ind'), grouped by the the L columns i.e. L1, L2, L3 after converting the 'data.frame' to 'data.table'.  Then we reshape from 'long' to 'wide' using `dcast` from the devel version of `data.table`.

```
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
d1 <- melt(setNames(L, seq_along(L)))
setDT(d1)[, ind:= c('start', 'end')[1:.N], .(L1, L2, L3)]
res <- setnames(dcast(d1, L1+L2~ind, value.var='value'), 
               1:2, c('config', 'alpha'))
res[,c(1:2, 4:3)]
#   config alpha start end
#1:      1     1     0   0
#2:      1     2     0   0
#3:      1     3    33  37
#4:      2     1     0   0
#5:      2     2     0   0
#6:      2     3    29  33
```

For the second `list` ('L1'), we do the same procedure.  We can change the column names as in the previous case.

```
d2 <- melt(setNames(L1, seq_along(L1)))
setDT(d2)[, ind:= 1:.N, .(L1, L2)]
dcast(d2, L1+L2~ind, value.var='value')
```

Comment: Wow, this seems quite complex.  The code I was trying elsewhere was this

test = data.frame(0,0,0,0)
 test = lapply(seq_along(master_init), function(x) lapply(seq_along(master_init[[x]]), function(y) lapply(seq_along(master_init[[x]][[y]]), function(z) 
 { 
  test <<- rbind(test,c(x,alpha_set$alpha[y],master_init[[x]][[y]][[z]][1],master_init[[x]][[y]][[z]][2]))
  
  #print(c(x,alpha_set$alpha[y],master_init[[x]][[y]][[z]][1],master_init[[x]][[y]][[z]][2]))
 })))

Comment: That doesn't look good, but is to say why can't I just loop over the list using lapply and assign whatever x,y,z output to something else?  Should I use replace perhaps?

Comment: @rdevn00b  If you just want the value columns, TommyO'Dell's code looks simple enough.  It is only because you mentioned about the index as columns, I used `melt`.  For me, it is just `reshaping` to 'long' with `melt` and then back to `wide` using `dcast`.

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't a complete answer, it may get you started on the right path.

```
L1 <- list(list(list(c(0,0)),list(c(0,0)),list(c(33,37))), list(list(c(0,0)),list(c(0,0)),list(c(29,33))))
L2 <- list(list(c(0,0)), list(c(1,4),c(5,9)), list(c(0,0)))

as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(L1), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))

  V1 V2
1  0  0
2  0  0
3 33 37
4  0  0
5  0  0
6 29 33

as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(L2), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
  V1 V2
1  0  0
2  1  4
3  5  9
4  0  0
```

Comment: This answer does not give config_id nor alpha, is there a way to modify it to do so?